# th and td width changes on hide and show columns

Tags: html, angularjs, css, angular-datatables

using angular datatables but not using colvis functionality of angularjs datatables instead using ng-show/hide to hide columns. The show/hide functionality works as expected but the width of th and td changes. I tried  table-layout:fixed; but that does not help.

here is the html code

```
              <div class="container">
                        <table id="taskSearch"
                               datatable="ng"
                               dt-options="dtOptions"
                               class="table table-bordered table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th ng-show="checkboxModel.pn">Policy Number</th>
                                    <th ng-show="checkboxModel.lob">LOB</th>
                                    <th ng-show="checkboxModel.state">State</th>
                                    <th ng-show="checkboxModel.firstInsuredFirstName">First Insured First Name</th>
                                    <th ng-show="checkboxModel.firstInsuredLastName">First Insured Last Name</th>
                                    <th ng-show="checkboxModel.transEffDate">Transaction Effective Date</th>
                                    <th ng-show="checkboxModel.policyEffDate">Policy Effective Date</th>
                                    <th ng-show="checkboxModel.receivedPassDate">Received Pass Date</th>
                                    <th ng-show="checkboxModel.documentType">Document Type</th>
                                    <th ng-show="checkboxModel.inWorkflow">In WorkFlow?</th>
                                    <th ng-show="checkboxModel.workflowTaskType">WorkFlow Task Type</th>
                                    <th ng-show="checkboxModel.batchName">Batch Name</th>
                                    <th ng-show="checkboxModel.systemOfRecord">System of Record</th>
                                    <th ng-show="checkboxModel.taskPinName">Task PIN and Name</th>
                                    <th ng-show="checkboxModel.taskStatus">Task Status</th>
                                    <th ng-show="checkboxModel.taskComplexity">Task Complexity</th>
                                    <th ng-show="checkboxModel.taskCompleteDate">Task Complete Date</th>
                                    <th ng-show="checkboxModel.taskActualCycleTime">Task Actual Cycle Time</th>
                                    <th ng-show="checkboxModel.taskTargetCycleTime">Task Target Cycle Time</th>
                                    <th ng-show="checkboxModel.docCreationSource">Doc Creation Source</th>
                                    <th ng-show="checkboxModel.documentTypeCode">Document Type Code</th>
                                    <th ng-show="checkboxModel.policyExpirationDate">Policy Expiration Date</th>
                                    <th ng-show="checkboxModel.scanPinName">Scan/Import PIN and Name</th>
                                    <th ng-show="checkboxModel.fileName">File Name</th>
                                    <th ng-show="checkboxModel.uniqueDocId">Unique Doc ID</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr ng-repeat="ts in taskSearch">
                                    <td ng-show="checkboxModel.pn">
                                        {{ ts.policyNumber }}
                                    </td>
                                    <td ng-show="checkboxModel.lob">
                                        {{ ts.lob }}
                                    </td>
                                    <td ng-show="checkboxModel.state">
                                        {{ ts.jurisCode}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td ng-show="checkboxModel.firstInsuredLastName">
                                        {{ ts.firstInsuredFirstName}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td ng-show="checkboxModel.firstInsuredFirstName">
                                        {{ ts.firstInsuredLastName}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td ng-show="checkboxModel.transEffDate">
                                        {{ ts.transEffDate }}
                                    </td>
                                    <td ng-show="checkboxModel.policyEffDate">
                                        {{ ts.policyEffDate }}
                                    </td>
                                    <td ng-show="checkboxModel.receivedPassDate">
                                        {{ ts.receivedPassDate}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td ng-show="checkboxModel.documentType">
                                        {{ ts.docTypeDesc}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td ng-show="checkboxModel.inWorkflow">
                                        {{ ts.inWorkflow}}
                                    </td>


                                    <td ng-show="checkboxModel.workflowTaskType">
                                        {{ ts.workflowTaskType }}
                                    </td>
                                    <td ng-show="checkboxModel.batchName">
                                        {{ ts.batchName }}
                                    </td>
                                    <td ng-show="checkboxModel.systemOfRecord">
                                        {{ ts.systemOfRecord}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td ng-show="checkboxModel.taskPinName">
                                        {{ ts.taskPinName}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td ng-show="checkboxModel.taskStatus">
                                        {{ ts.taskStatus}}
                                    </td>

                                    <td ng-show="checkboxModel.taskComplexity">
                                        {{ ts.taskComplexity }}
                                    </td>
                                    <td ng-show="checkboxModel.taskCompleteDate">
                                        {{ ts.taskCompleteDate }}
                                    </td>
                                    <td ng-show="checkboxModel.taskActualCycleTime">
                                        {{ ts.taskActualCycleTime}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td ng-show="checkboxModel.taskTargetCycleTime">
                                        {{ ts.taskTargetCycleTime}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td ng-show="checkboxModel.docCreationSource">
                                        {{ ts.tocCreateSource}}
                                    </td>

                                    <td ng-show="checkboxModel.documentTypeCode">
                                        {{ ts.docTypeCode }}
                                    </td>
                                    <td ng-show="checkboxModel.policyExpirationDate">
                                        {{ ts.policyExpDate }}
                                    </td>
                                    <td ng-show="checkboxModel.scanPinName">
                                        {{ ts.ingestionUserDisplayName}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td ng-show="checkboxModel.fileName">
                                        {{ ts.importFilename}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td ng-show="checkboxModel.uniqueDocId">
                                        {{ ts.documentID}}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

css is the bootstrap css

```
table {
max-width: 100%;
 background-color: transparent;  
}

  th {
   text-align: left;
  }

  .table {  
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px; 
   }

   .table thead > tr > th,
   .table tbody > tr > th,
   .table tfoot > tr > th,
  .table thead > tr > td,
   .table tbody > tr > td,
   .table tfoot > tr > td {
   padding: 8px;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
  vertical-align: top;
 border-top: 1px solid #dddddd; 

}

 .table thead > tr > th {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #dddddd;
 }
```

hide and show using angular

```
                      <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <li>
                                                <label class="toggle-vis">
                                                    <input type="checkbox"                         ng-model="checkboxModel.pn">
                                                    Policy Number
                                                </label>
                                            </li>
                                            <hr class="style1">
                                            <li>
                                                <label class="toggle-vis">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.firstInsuredLastName">
                                                    First Insured Last Name
                                                </label>
                                            </li>
                                            <hr class="style1">
                                            <li>
                                                <label class="toggle-vis">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.documentType">
                                                    Document Type
                                                </label>
                                            </li>
                    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: can you post some of your code too? HTML/js/CSS

Comment: added html and css

Comment: Can you show the code that does the hiding and showing too? Also, what's the use of the `table thead > tr > th` stuff if you're not nesting tables?

Comment: Also, i have observed something new..if i minimize and maximize the browser the th and td are matching with same width..

Answer (score 0):

for the one still having this issue, the wrong resize of the table happens 70% when you hide and show the table, cell or row with the wrong option in the display.
Table's should not be '**display:block**' or '**display:inline-block**';

Here a detailed list of what each display does: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

And here is a sample where you can hide or show a tbody based on a codition:

```css
.d-table-row-group{
   display: table-row-group;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered mt-3">
<thead class="noselect">
   <tr>
      <th scope="column">Table header 1</th>
      <th scope="column">Table header 2</th>
      <th scope="column">Table header 3</th>
      <th scope="column">Table header 4</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody [class]="conditionHere ? 'd-none': 'd-table-row-group'">
   <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```